# WScript.Shell.Exec - read output from stdout

Tags: vbscript

My VBScript does not show the results of any command I execute. I know the command gets executed but I would like to capture the result.

I have tested many ways of doing this, for example the following:

```
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2
strCommand = "ping.exe 127.0.0.1"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)

Select Case WshShellExec.Status
   Case WshFinished
       strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
   Case WshFailed
       strOutput = WshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll
 End Select

WScript.StdOut.Write strOutput  'write results to the command line
WScript.Echo strOutput          'write results to default output
```

But it does not print any results. How do I capture `StdOut` and `StdErr`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`WScript.Shell.Exec()` returns **immediately**, even though the process it starts does not. If you try to read `Status` or `StdOut` right away, there won't be anything there.

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx) suggests using the following loop:

```
Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

This checks `Status` every 100ms until it changes. Essentially, you have to wait until the process completes, then you can read the output.

With a few small changes to your code, it works fine:

```
Const WshRunning = 0
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2
strCommand = "ping.exe 127.0.0.1"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)

Do While WshShellExec.Status = WshRunning
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Select Case WshShellExec.Status
   Case WshFinished
       strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
   Case WshFailed
       strOutput = WshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll()
 End Select

WScript.StdOut.Write(strOutput)  'write results to the command line
WScript.Echo(strOutput)          'write results to default output
```

Comment: If the environment you're running in doesn't have access to `WScript.Sleep`, you can remove that line and perform a busy wait

Answer (score 1):

You should read both streams INSIDE the loop as well as after it. When your process is verbose then it will block on the I/O buffer when this buffer will not be emptyfied succesively!!!

Comment: But how to keep it from blocking inside the loop? Won't a readAll() block until there's data on it?

Comment: oExec is a Shell object, two variables are gathering the stream contents. You can drop it if it is too long....

Do While oExec.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    If Not oExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream Then
 vErrStr = vErrStr & oExec.StdErr.ReadAll
    End If
    If Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then
 vOutStr = vOutStr & oExec.StdOut.ReadAll
    End If
Loop

Answer (score 0):

I think [Tomek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308275/11498) is good, but incomplete.

Here's a code example.

```
Private Sub ExecuteCommand(sCommand$)
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    
    Dim oExec As Object, oOut As TextStream
    
    'Exec the command
    Set oExec = wsh.Exec(sCommand$)
    Set oOut = oExec.StdOut
    
    'Wait for the command to finish
    While Not oOut.AtEndOfStream
        Call Debug.Print(oOut.ReadLine)
    Wend
    
    Select Case oExec.Status
       Case WshFinished
       Case WshFailed
           Err.Raise 1004, "EndesaSemanal.ExecuteCommand", "Error: " & oExec.StdErr.ReadAll()
     End Select
End Sub
```