# Issues trying to close a bat file from a vbs script

Tags: vbscript

i'm trying to help my little brother with a vbs script file, i've never used vbs, and i'm having serious issues on finding out how to end a bat file that i've opened with the vbs script after 2 seconds

I've tried terminate but it doesn't work, even running another shell with taskkill and the name of process but nothing

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\\Users\me\Desktop\Samples\t.bat"
Wscript.Sleep 2000`
```

I would like the bat file to close itself after 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Use the Exec command instead of Run.
https://ss64.com/vb/exec.html

"Unlike .Run method, .Exec returns an object which returns additional information about the process started."

This example uses cmd.exe /k (the /k will keep the cmd.exe window open, which will be killed after your 2 second timeout even if your bat script logic finishes before that)

```
Dim shll : Set shll = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Rt = shll.Exec("cmd.exe /k C:\Temp\test.bat") : wscript.sleep 2000 : 
Rt.Terminate
```

If you want to return the output of the bat script you will need to read this [WScript.Shell.Exec - read output from stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492879/wscript-shell-exec-read-output-from-stdout), and use logic similar to:

```
Const WshRunning = 0
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2
strCommand = "C:\Temp\test.bat"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)

Do While oExec.Status = 0 
    WScript.Sleep 1000 
    If Not oExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream Then 
        vErrStr = vErrStr & oExec.StdErr.ReadAll 
    End If 

    If Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then 
        vOutStr = vOutStr & oExec.StdOut.ReadAll 
    End If 
Loop


WScript.StdOut.Write(vErrStr)
WScript.Echo(vOutStr)
```

It all depends on what your bat file is doing really, and the reason you need to kill it after x seconds.

Edit:
Because your batch file is a continuous loop, it may confuse ReadAll of the output stream.  You might be best using something such as (note that you will not see real-time output):

```
Dim strCommand : strCommand  = "C:\Temp\test.bat"

Dim WshShell : Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'execute command
Dim oExec : Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)

'wait 2 seconds
WScript.Sleep 2000

'terminate command
oExec.terminate

'get output
wscript.echo oExec.StdOut.ReadAll

Set oExec = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, whenever I run this script it opens and closes the CMD file without executing the bat script

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, sadly whenever i run the updated script you gave me it opens forever a cmd page and doesn't do anything. The bat script is: @echo off :a echo hello world goto a It should do things for 2 seconds and then close itself

Comment: It says that it expects the end of a statement on the first line

Comment: ...@claudiunderthehood try again.

Comment: Now It works but it opens a Windows Script Host window with hello world that lasts forever

Comment: It shouldn't last forever. That should be one prompt containing all of the output of the bat file in the last 2 seconds. Your bat file is a constant loop from what you said earlier on, so it will contain multiple lines of  'hello world'.

Comment: If you dont want a popup you will need to force your script to open with cscript.exe instead of wscript.exe. Or alternatively write the output to a text file etc.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and for you help!