# SQL-Query over Powershell, Output over .vbs

Tags: sql, powershell, vbscript, scom

I am currently hardstuck at this problem and I hope there is a solution.

I need to run a SQL query on one of our servers, where i check for the creation of a user.
The main problem is, that i need to run this query over vbs, respectively in a vbs launched powershell script.

My ps code is running, but i am unable to get the output over vbs.

This is the ps code:

```
$command = function Invoke-SQL {Param( [string]$SqlCommand  );
    $PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8';
    $E = Get-OdbcDsn -Name SQL_UserCheck;
    $driver = $E.DriverName;
    $server= $E.Attribute.Server;
    $database = $E.Attribute.Database;
    $connectionString = "Server=$server; integrated security = true";
    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString);
    $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection);
    $connection.Open();
    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command;
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
    $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null;
    $connection.Close();
    $dataSet.Tables | Format-List;  
} 


    Invoke-SQL -SqlCommand "DECLARE @tracefile VARCHAR(256) 
                    SELECT @tracefile = CAST(value AS VARCHAR(256)) 
                    FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT) 
                    WHERE traceid = 1 
                    AND property = 2 
                    SELECT NTUserName, SessionLoginName, SPID, TargetLoginName, StartTime, ServerName 
                    FROM ::fn_trace_gettable(@tracefile, DEFAULT) trc 
                    INNER JOIN sys.trace_events evt ON trc.EventClass = evt.trace_event_id 
                    WHERE trc.EventClass IN (108, 109, 110) AND ObjectName ='sysadmin' 
                    ORDER BY trc.StartTime";
```

This is my try at putting the whole thing into a .vbs

```
pscommand = "<powershellscript from above>"
cmd = "powershell.exe -noprofile  -command " & pscommand
Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set executor = shell.Exec(cmd)
executor.StdIn.Close
strStarter = executor.StdOut.ReadAll
WScript.Echo strStarter
```

But for some reason, the output stays empty.
I already checked for te quotation marks and replaced them all with "" instead of ".
I also checked this with WScript.Echo "" and all the " get transfered correctly.

Sadly, i am no out of ideas and have no clue where to start.

In the end, i need to get this out of vbs as either a single string or an array, so i can put these into propertybags.

Thanks in advance for all possible help.

Comment: `.Exec` returns immediately, even if the process it starts is not finished. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32493083) resolve the issue?

Comment: Sadly not. I think the problem lies in the Datatype of $dataset. If i run GetType() on the variable it is System.Data.DataTable.

Another problem i face with this, it seems like all values get written into a single 
cell, so with multiple values it gets even more problematic.

Comment: Write the data into a file and read it in VBS?

Comment: Writing this into a file sadly isnt an option, since i need to run this script over scom on multiple servers. Creating files is a no-go for me here i am affraid.

Comment: May I ask why you cannot use PowerShell directly? Or, perhaps, rewrite the whole thin in C#?