# Unable to get results of Confirm-SecureBootUEFI

Tags: vbscript

I want to get the true or false value for `Confirm-SecureBootUEFI` in my VBScript. But every time I run it, I get a blank result (see image below)

```
'Check Secure Boot
Dim SecureBoot
cmd = "powershell.exe confirm-SecureBootUEFI"
Set SecureBoot = objShell.Exec(cmd)
msgbox SecureBoot.StdOut.ReadAll
```

Here is the result I receive:

[image: Blank Result Window]

[WScript.Shell.Exec - read output from stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492879/wscript-shell-exec-read-output-from-stdout) Does not help since that is what I was referencing when I wrote that script.

`StdIn.Close` shouldn't need to be there, but whether or not it is, the result is the same: nothing. I've cleaned up the code to the base of what should work.

Comment: Why `SecureBoot.StdIn.Close`? You're not providing input so just don't need this at all.

Comment: If the duplicate target is what you have used to get to this point, how come you've missed the part about delaying the `Stdout.ReadAll` for a few milliseconds in the accepted answer? Quote - "`WScript.Shell.Exec()` returns **immediately**, even though the process it starts does not. If you try to read `Status` or `StdOut` right away, there won't be anything there."

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who come across this, try doing a StdErr.ReadAll.
My issue was permission level.

Comment: That’s not the Standard Output though, maybe if you asked for the Error output.