# Returned string from PowerShell to VBS script is empty

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I am trying to run a powershell script in vbs which should return a string.
The returned string then should be saved in an registry key as value.

But when I want to build the registry key value, the returned string always is empty even though I can display it correctly with MsgBox.

```
psFile = "C:\Temp\file.ps1"
cmd = "powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -File " & psFile
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
Set shellExec = oShell.Exec(cmd)
shellExec.StdIn.Close
returnedString = shellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
registryValue = returnedString 'is empty
msgbox returnedString 'shows correct value
```

file.ps1:

```
Write-Output "String"
```

How can i return the value correctly?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32493083/4190564) answer your question?

Comment: It is implied by the linked duplicate, but to spell it out: `.Exec()` is _asynchronous_, so you must explicitly wait for the process to terminate to ensure that you can predictably read all of its stdout and stderr output. You probably just got lucky with your `msgbox` call in that by the time it executed the stdout output just so _happened to_ be already available, but not before.

Comment: Another option is to use the `Run` method which supports waiting for completion. Then, instead of using StdOut, have the PowerShell script write the result to the registry, which, of course, you can read back in VBScript.